# How could Moshe write on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, midrash, melacha-creative-work, moshe-rabbeinu, writing-printing

I once saw this question in the magazine *Kolmus*:

> There's a tradition that Moshe wrote thirteen *sifrei Torah* on the day of his death.
>   However, there are many opinions that Moshe died on Shabbos, so how could he have written on Shabbos?

Comment: Maybe the agaddos are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Please provide a source that moshe died on shabbos

Comment: Obviously mutually-exclusive Midrashim, as often happens. Unless you want to say he died Friday night, and wrote the Seforim on Friday. Sometimes in Halacha (like in Korbanot) the night follows the day.

Comment: @user3949142:  It's from the Zohar.  See http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.292 (saif vav), and the dispute of the Beit Hadash.

Comment: Did _Kolmus_ provide an answer? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2151/5323 || http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @dannyschomann its interesting that you bring such an answer the chasam sofer i qoute in my answer (shu"t cheilek vov siman tes) explains something similar that while its shabbos down here it is no longer shabbos "up there" but he pushes away that answer

Comment: http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?CategoryID=1141&ArticleID=4779

Answer (score 5):

the chasam sofer (shu"t cheilek vov siman tes) qoutes the shaloh answering this question moshe wrote the sifrei torah "bi-hasvoas hakulmos (he wrote with feathers in between each of his hands) which is no better then writing with your weaker hand and that is only a derabanan (which was only institued later)

a lot better of a question would be how was it phisycaly possible for moshe to write thirteen sifrei torah in one day (and its not qouted anywhere that it was done thru a miracle)?!!!!

even more then that the mitzvah for every jew to write a sefer torah was said on the day of ( very close to) moshe's passing its not brought anywhere that the 600,000 jews (at least start)  to make that much parchment and ink and all other necessery items and begin writing all on that day?!

so some mefarshim (maharzav to devorim rabah on this parshah (vayeilach) perek tes seif tes) and others say that moshe wrote the 13 sifrei torah before **and he finished on the day of his passing** 
(acording to this you can also understand ( as the rambam writes in his hakdomoh to his pirush hamishnayus) about all the jews who had a mitzvah to write their own sefer torah they wrote during the forty years in the desert (the rambam uses the words hamitzvah hahie bimigilos) that they wrote a few "booklets" and finished it off all on zayin addar (the day of moshes passing)

but (amongst other questions) we only find regarding moshe that he wrote thirteen sifrei torah if all the jews at least finished their sifrei torah on that day it is very odd that there is no mention of this great siyum of **over 600,000 sifrei torah???** espacialy if it mentions the thirteen that moshe wrote

to answer all these questions you can look at likutei sichos cheilek chof daled page 207ff (i would only ruin the beautiful answer the rebbe gives and there he explains based off his answers the importance of each jew to have aletter in a sefer torah)

Comment: Doesn't a Sofer have to write Derekh Kesiva? If so, it isn't a Shinui for Shabbat either.